# Factoring of $x^3-3x^2+30x-1$

Tags: cubics

I need help factoring 
\begin{align}
x^3-3x^2+30x-1=0.\tag{1}
\end{align}
Any thoughts? I've tried the old guess and check method with long division and $\left(x-\frac{1}{2}\right),\left(x-1\right),\left(x-12\right),\left(x-6\right)$, all to no avail.

Thank you for your time,

Comment: only possible rational factors of the cubic is $\pm 1.$ neither of them is a factor. it has a root $x = 0.03344$ according to my ti-83.

Comment: Is it possible that $30$ should be just $3$?  Then this factors nicely as $(x-1)^3=0$

Comment: @vadim123 I only wish :P

Comment: Chances are that if this is an exercise from some class then either there's a mistake in one of the polynomial's coefficients or else the lecturer is devilish evil. If this stems from *other* problem then the "devilish" part can be diminished to "awfully".

Answer (score -1):

Do not look for a neat number(check [wolframalpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Solve%5B%7Bx%5E3-3x%5E2%2B30x-1%20%20%3D%3D%200%7D%2C%20x%5D))

Comment: Wow that's a hideous result I suppose. But how might I obtain a result like that?

Comment: @jm324354 My favourite method is Cardano's method.